# Delete specific words from text file in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file something like this:

```
[123456]
fhbfvhfh
[128654]
dfgfdgd
[745213]
gdffggbhgh
[986452]
kjijki
```

Is there any code or anyway to remove the two brackets and what they contain in one time in notepad++? Because I have a thousands of those brackets and I want to remove them without losing my time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove those square brackets with its content with [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/). Using notepad++ press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and click the `"replace"` tab. Make sure you have the `"regular-expression"` checkbox activated and search for `\[(.*?)\]`. Leave the `"replace"` field empty, press replace all and then you have all brackes removed with its content in one step.

For an explanation of `\[(.*?)\]` :

`\[` and `\]` captures the square brackets. Inside of those brackets `(.*?)` matches everything and captures it.